# How to crop an image in swift

Tags: swift, image-processing

I want to crop an image from camera. There should be a rectangle border in the camera preview and the result will be the cropped image, like this example:

[image: ID Scan]

Answer (score 2):

Combining [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping) with the deprecated answer by [Pranavan Sp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838302/461982) to skip the bells and whistles, you would get:

```
extension UIImage {

    func cropToRect(rect: CGRect!) -> UIImage? {

        let scaledRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * self.scale, y: rect.origin.y * self.scale, width: rect.size.width * self.scale, height: rect.size.height * self.scale);


        guard let imageRef: CGImage = self.cgImage?.cropping(to:scaledRect)
        else {
            return nil
        }

        let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        return croppedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIImage {  
    // Crops an input image (self) to a specified rect
    func cropToRect(rect: CGRect!) -> UIImage? {
        // Correct rect size based on the device screen scale
        let scaledRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale, rect.origin.y * self.scale, rect.size.width * self.scale, rect.size.height * self.scale);
        // New CGImage reference based on the input image (self) and the specified rect
        let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, scaledRect);
        // Gets an UIImage from the CGImage
        let result = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        // Returns the final image, or NULL on error
        return result;
    }    
}

// Crops an image to 100x100 pixels, 150px from left and 200px from top
let exampleImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageFile")
let croppedImage = exampleImage?.cropToRect(CGRectMake(150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0))
if croppedImage != nil {
    // Your image was cropped
} else {
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Comment: Thnaks a Lot!!!

Answer (score -4):

[image: Filler screenshot of code]

Hi you can resize your image with this code.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size
    let widthRation = targetSize.width / size.width
    let heightRation = targetSize.height / size.height
    var newSize: CGSize
    if (widthRatio > heightRation {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

Comment: This isn't YouTube, so it seems like a lot of extra work to show a visual capture of your code instead of pasting it.